# Anyone knows the proof of this formula?

Tags: statistics

X is for continuous random variable and it's nonnegative. 
Then this is the formula.

$$E(X)=\int_0^\infty(1-F(x))dx$$

Does anyone know the proof?
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Just integrate by part. (remember $\text{PDF}(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\text{CDF}(x)$

Comment: @achillehui A PDF might be lacking here.

Comment: One of the most duplicated questions on the site? (And one needs no PDF, indeed.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Write RHS as $$\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}1_{(x,\infty)}(y)dF(y)dx$$
and switch the order of integration.

Answer (score 0):

Provided there is a density function, you can do this:

$$\int_0^\infty (1-F(x)) \mathrm{d} x = \int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty f(y)\mathrm{d} y \mathrm{d} x = \int_0^\infty \int_0^y f(y) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \int_0^\infty y f(y)\mathrm{d}y = \mathrm{E}(X)
$$

Otherwise look at drhab's answer.

Comment: $X$ has continuous distribution, but not necessarily absolutely continuous. It can be that no PDF exists.